# Help with symlink

Tags: symbolic-link

I accidentally changed permission to 000 on symlink:

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

In effect ubuntu 15.10 can't execute any bash command (binary). In this situation **chroot** from live cd is not working. System is not launching (kernel panic). Rescue mode also is not launching. How to (restore permissions of this symlink and) make system bootable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I mislead myself because symlink:

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

shows *lrwxrwxrwx* permissions. It directs to this shared object :

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so*
```

Which (permissions were changed to 000) is **dynamic linker/loader**. It finds and load the shared libraries needed by a program, prepare the program to run, and then run it. It lost permissions to do anything, so it couldn't launch any needed library making system unbootale.

Executing (from live system):

```
sudo chmod 755 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so*
```

solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You have to boot from CD oder USB. Or mount the harddrive into another PC.

Comment: Making this symlink again is not working

Comment: Because the name is already occupied? Restore the permissions to: lrwxrwxrwx .

Comment: When i boot from live it shows this symlink permissions as you wrote, but system is "dead"

Comment: The just mounted filesystem or do you try to chroot? Don't chroot.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/524097)

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Because EdID provided the wrong information, that the permissions of the linking file are 000, not the ones of the file linked to.  And of course, if the system is broken of that reason, you can't chroot into the system, but have to boot from a different system or mount the fs from a live cd, as EdID did.